# desktop larger than the view

Tags: windows

Ok, I need a general help here.
I am looking for a software solution, not a code solution.

I would like to magnify the whole area of my desktop so that i will see only a part of it.    when I will move my mouse to each edge it will move the view to that part.
(this is very popular with iphone remote control apps . do you know if I will find an app for it in for winXP?  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at Mark Russinovich's [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434).

Comment: stackoverflow.com is a wonderfull place. 10x man.